# Laravel install in sub folder showing 404 page

Tags: php, laravel

I moved Laravel file to subfolder and hit url `localhost/test/public` it's working fine but I want to use url `localhost/test`. I put `.htaccess` in test folder but than `localhost/test` showing 404

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a .htaccess file in your root path

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Mover `index.php` and `.htacces` file from `public` folder to
  `test` or App Root folder.
- Modify `index.php` like this

  `require __DIR__.'vendor/autoload.php';`

  `$app = require_once __DIR__.'bootstrap/app.php';`

And if your css and js stops working add `{{asset('public')}}/` before your imports, for example

```
<link href="{{ asset('public') }}/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('public') }}/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then you can access your website at http://localhost/test